# How to route "/" to public/index.html in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, routes

My Facebook app uses a AS3 front end and a APIish Rails backend.

Facebook requires your "canvas page" (your app page sucked into the Facebook chrome) either be dynamic (index.erb) or a directory (end with "/"). Since I don't know Rails views, I went with the url of "myapp.herokuapps.com/".

Heroku logs give this error:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/")

How can I match "/" to the index file?

match "/" => ????

I am used to routing resources, but not static pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display a static page as your root, you should be using the High Voltage gem. This allows you to add static pages to your site as follows:

- Add `gem 'high_voltage'` to your `Gemfile`
- Put your static `home.html.erb` page in `/app/views/pages/`
- Route to your static page with `root to: => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'home'`

No redirects are necessary.

The High Voltage docs can be found at https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a root_path in your routes.rb file

So `root :to => 'YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME#YOUR_CONTROLLER_ACTION'` should do it.

If you wanted to map it to a file, then just give the name of the file in the public directory, so if you wanted to map public/index.html to root then this would work:

```
root :to => 'index'
```

Comment: So "/" is automatically matched to the root? So how then would I map the root to a page rather than a controller? root :to=> "public/index.html"?

Comment: See my updated answer.  Please accept and upvote if it works for you!

Comment: the route is still expected expecting an action param: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:171:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)

Comment: do you have a file called index.html sitting in your public directory?  This works just fine for me.

Comment: Ok, interesting, this is a feature of Rails 3.1.  It appears that this can't easily be done in Rails 3.0.9.

Comment: I do have the file there. Are you sure your root is being used when you do this?

Comment: Lol, ok so after all that, I think all you need to do is simply put a public/index.html file and remove the route.  That will always be rendered when you visit '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are correct; however, the folks at thoughtbot recommend the following:

1. Under "config/initializers/" create the file "high_voltage.rb"
2. Write in the following code

   ```
   HighVoltage.configure do |config|
       config.home_page = "home"
   end
   ```
3. Restart your server

You can check the documentation at https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#specifying-a-root-path